# python/django - assigning to global variable in decorator

Tags: python, django

I use thread-locals in order to implement user-based theming. First I wrote a middleware and have had no issues. Now I am converting it to a decorator and having an embarrassing issue. Here's the simplified code:

```
# views.py

_thread_locals = threading.local()

def foo_decorator(f):
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global _thread_locals
        _thread_locals.bar = kwargs['bar']
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wraps(f)(_wrapper)

@foo_decorator
def some_view(request, bar):
    # Stuff here
    # Here _thread_locals.bar exists

# This is called by the template loader:
def get_theme():
    return _thread_locals.bar # Error
```

What I get when get_theme is called is a complaint that bar attribute does not exist. Where is it gone? Most probably I am missing something related to scoping in closures, but can't figure out what.

Comment: In another thread. That's why you don't do this.

Comment: I am using devserver, so there's a single thread

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me, but only if `some_view` is called before `get_theme`.

The devserver kills your process and restarts a new one every time you modify a file in your project directory.  Your thread data is of course lost when this is done.  If you see the `"Validating models..."` message, your thread data is already lost.

Comment: BTW - I have a strong feeling there is a better way to solve your "user-based theming" problem other than using threading.

Comment: If you ever come across a more elegant solution to user-based theming, please share it. I did really serious googling about it but couldn't find one.

Comment: shanyu: How about keeping the user theme in the session?

Comment: I would love to :) But Django's template loaders don't have access to the request object. I think I am not abusing thread locals in this case as I write to and read from it within the same request.

Comment: @shanyu: Who exactly calls get_theme and why couldn't it be called from the view itself and pass the theme in the context to the template?

Comment: If you want to have user-based theming, at every request you need to identify the user and use this information to determine which template to load. The user-based templates are loaded by a custom template loader. Django's template loaders have no access to request object. So what needs to be done is: 1. identify user & determine theme, 2. store this info in a thread local, 3. when the custom template loader is called (automatically by Django), make it obtain the theme info from the thread local.

Comment: I don't want to specify a correct template in the view, this will break the ability to fall-back to the standard template if no custom templates exists for the user. Therefore I am using a template loader here. For similar examples take a look at: https://bitbucket.org/daks/django-userthemes https://github.com/shestera/django-multisite

Comment: mmm.... I'll have to sleep over this.  Anyway, as I said the code above works.  Just make sure you keep the call order correct.  In a decorator, call get_theme after calling the view function.

Comment: I got it working by moving the decorator and get_theme to a separate module. Have no idea what the problem is..

Answer (score 0):

Changing the django template loader to support theming is what I have done.

```
`def load_template_for_user(user, template_name):
    """
    Loads a template for a particular user from a theme.
    This is used in the generic baseviews and also in the theme template tags

1. First try and load the template with the users theme.
2. Second if that doesn't exist, try and load the template from the default theme
3. Send the template name to the loader to see if we can catch it.
4. With the order of the template loaders, the template loader above will try and
   load from the Database.
   This will happen if the user tries to use {% extends %} or {% include %} tags
 """

    _theme = get_theme_for_user(user)
    _theme_template_name = "" + _theme.name + "/templates/" + template_name

    # Get the default theme
    _default_theme = get_default_theme()
    _default_theme_template_name = "" + _default_theme.name + "/templates/" + template_name

    _templates=[_theme_template_name, _default_theme_template_name, template_name]

    try:
        return loader.select_template(_templates)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist, e:
        log.error("Couldn't load template %s" % template_name)
        raise
    except Exception, e:
        log.error("Couldn't load template, generic Exception %s" % e)
        raise
```

`

Obviously there is some code in there that you can't see but its basically looking at models to see what the default_theme is, and get_theme_for_user looks at the UserProfile object to see what they have set their theme to.